# Spring / SpringBoot: which one is the web context, and which one the backend?

Tags: spring, service, udp

I would like to start an udp service in the backend (and *not* in the frontend) context (especially only *once*, because only one service can establish the socket, not both).

How can I figure out, in which context my bean is located, to open the port in one of both only?

Thanks in advice for any ideas

Greez

Comment: What in your mind is backend and frontend?

Comment: Hi! I mean, that when using jpa and mvc I noticed, that there are 2 contexts (i found out this by logging the constructors during runtime, because my schedulers seamed to run twice) - at least in spring (not in spring boot?)

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. What in your mind is the frontend and backend? The fact that things run twice basically means your separation is wrong (and I suspect in many other applications as well). I suspect you have a `ContextLoaderListener` and `DispatcherServlet` both loading either the same xml/java config or at least using the same `component-scan`. Which basicaly means you are loading your application twice. Which has nothing to do with front-end and/or back-end it has all to do with a wrong configuration.